# Create a record with a default type, with specific keys being another

Tags: typescript, types

I want to make an object with a default type, with a few specific keys with their own, completely unrelated types. The following is an attempt I've made with intersections.

```js
type StringObject = Record<string, string>;

// Define an interface or type that specifies the exception
interface DollarSignIsNumber {
    $?: number;
}

// Use an intersection type to combine them
type SpecificType = StringObject & DollarSignIsNumber;

// Example usage
const example: SpecificType = {
    //~~~~~~~ Type '{ name: string; age: string; $: number; }' is not assignable to type 'StringObject'.
    name: "John",
    age: "30",
    $: 123
    // anyother: 324 - error
};
```

It doesn't work because as soon as the unique types are introduced, it stops conforming to the StringObject type.

Comment: This is not possible. See the linked q/a for more information and various workarounds.